# Restrict zero in a numeric only input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code and it it allows to enter digits only. How do I restrict from entering zero (0) as the first digit?

```
$('.btn').keypress(function(e) {
      var code = e.which;
      if(($(this).val().indexOf(".") == -1 && code == 46) || (code >= 48 && code <= 57) || (code == 8) || (code >= 48 && code <= 57)){
          return true;
        }       
       return false;
    })
    .bind('paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: read about regex http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: I'd suggest you not try to prevent entering 0 as the first digit.  Just clean up any leading zeroes before you actually use the field.  Remember you can get values into fields in ways other than just pressing keys such as copy/paste and drag/drop so trying to enforce things exactly from the keyboard doesn't keep you from having to clean up the value at the end anyway.  Also, trying to block the paste function is just downright annoying.  I hate sites that do that.  There's no good reason to block it because it's my business how I provide the input, not yours.

Comment: @Mate : thanks. Okay is this the way to do it `this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 48`? The problem now is that how to I use it with the `return` statement?

Comment: the comment above me is right on.  you should always validate on both ends.  you can check when the input loses focus for instant things but if you're sending the data somewhere, validate it again before you send it and/or before you use it on the server side.

Comment: @jfriend00: thanks certainly useful... Would you mind showing how to validate it via `keypress` function?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin: thanks. I'm validating input values in my php.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not interested in providing a solution that isn't the way I think the problem should be solved.  Maybe someone else will do it for you.

Comment: wow... so... alright... i'll still play. but... so, that would be incredibly confusing to the user, btw.  i would think my keyboard was broken.  if anything strip leading zeros on [`focusout`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) with `str = $('#my_input_box').val(); $('#my_input_box').val(str.replace(/^(-?)0+/,'$1'));`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Numbers only and restrict 0 as first digit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472758/numbers-only-and-restrict-0-as-first-digit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing such work requires quite a bit of advance JavaScript.

First you need to know whether the cursor / caret is in position 0. To do that you need to get the selection range. That varies depending on the browser you are using.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range

Code snippet (untested) for Firefox & SeaMonkey:

```
var range = document.createRange();
var pos = range.startOffset;
```

Then if pos is zero, you know the cursor is at the start and you can test whether the user pressed zero:

```
if(pos == 0 && code == 48)
{
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

However, you want to also think about the case where the user enters 100 and put his cursor or selection to include the 1 or 10. Now he hits delete and what's left is one zero (0). How to handle that case will very much depend on what you really want to offer in your UI. I have seem really annoying systems that would auto-delete the rest of the text because it does not match a valid answer, not giving you a way to fix it... I do believe that's not a good solution.

Another solution, which is what I generally do, is to let the user enter whatever in the field (well, in your case, allow for digits only, but any random number), then when the user clicks "Submit", then you verify the format. If the format is wrong, barf out an error. In that case, the comment about regex's by Mate applies well (although he did not explain anything in his comment, kindda sad).

Answer (score 0):

try this samples

```
$('#numeric').bind('keypress', function (event) {
var regex = new RegExp("^[1-9\b]+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
});
```